# Trying to understand MySQL Replication with SSL

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, ssl

I'm trying to get my head around the use of **SSL** with MySQL replication. 
I've spent all day reading blog posts / articles about this, and I'm still no closer to getting an answer to this question:

Essentially I'm trying to understand the relationship between the ca, client & server files.

In my fictional setup I have:

```
1 x Master DB - Main Site
5 x Slave DBs - Main Site
Each Slave DB connects to a Slave DB on a remote (all different) Customer Site.
```

Am I right in thinking therefore that I would:

1. generate the `ca-cert.pem` and `ca-key.pem` files on the Master DB
2. create a set of `client-xxx` and `server-xxx` files on each Slave DB (and a copy of the `ca-xxx.pem` files)
3. Onto each Customer DB I would copy the `ca-cert.pem`,`client-cert.pem`,`client-key.pem` from the matching Slave DB

If one of the customer DB's was compromised would I need to generate a new `ca-cert.pem` file on the master, and re-distribute it to all remaining slaves & customer DB's (requiring all my DB's to be restarted).
Or could I just delete the `server-cert.pem` file from that one slave server?

(obviously I could revoke the username/password - but I'm trying to understand the SSL side at present).

Answer (score 1):

Create the server and client cert/key files on the master server and then copy only the client cert/key files to each slave server and configure SSL replication. So basically you have the same client cert and key on all slave servers. If a slave gets compromised change the replication user's credentials.

Comment: But surely if I rely on the MySQL user credentials, then there is no need for the Client cert/key files. I can use the `ca-cert` file to encrypt the data. My understanding was the client files would become unique to that client/server pair. And then I could simply revoke those files to prevent a connection, Thus providing an additional layer of security over and above just relying on the MySQL user credentials.

Comment: IMHO, The point of having SSL replication is to encrypt the replicated data on-the-wire. if you are worried about your servers getting compromised then You should make sure that appropriate safeguards are inplace to prevent it. Put your db servers behind a firewall or a vpn where you can revoke access individually.

Answer (score 1):

The SSL keys are good for encrypting the transmission only - the data stored on the slaves, once transmitted, will be unencrypted. So, if a slave is compromised, the data will be compromised. It doesnt make any sense, as far as I understand, to protect the transmission key, if somebody will already have the entire data.

Comment: ok, but if customer1 is compromised, could they not 'potentially' use that key to try and access the other slave databases (assuming the rest of my security was quite lax)?